# Laravel adding blur to a picture in storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, imagick

I am saving the image in the store. Here I need to make a blurred version of the image.

```
$path = $request->file('file-upload-photo-profile')->store('public/profile');
        $user->photo_profile_url = 'storage/app/'.$path;
        $user->photo_profile = $path;
        /*
         * теперь блур
         * */
        $url=url('/').'/'.$user->photo_profile_url;
        $image=imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
        $imagick = new Imagick($image);
        $imagick->blurImage(5, 5);
         $imagick->getImageBlob();

        Storage::put('dssds.jpg',$imagick);
```

But the resulting file cannot be opened. This is not a picture.

Answer (score 1):

I think this url (photo_profile_url) that you're reading image from leads to 404 page cause your using laravel's url() function with internal path of storage. If you want to load an image from url, pass image's public url to Imagick.

Comment: The path is real. If you change it, then there will be another error.